# How to customize the name of purchase order in Odoo 8?

Tags: odoo-8

I wanna customize the name of purchase order like yyyymmdd_n. yymmdd is the date of the purchase order created, and n is the sequence number from 1 the order created on that day. However, the default value of n depends on the total count. I searched for the purchase order's creation in purchase.py and made some logging in some possible functions such as create_po, create_procurement_purchase_order. But when a new purchase order was created, none of them were called based on the logging details.

Is there someone who can give me a hand?

The method create in **class** **purchase_order** defines:

```
order = super(purchase_order, self).create(cr, uid, vals,context=context)
```

I am looking for the code for `super(...).create(...)

Update on 2016/5/11:
I found a simple way from [this](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/resetting-sequencer-padding-every-day-54738)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow . So what have you tried ? and what error did you get ? Can you provide some code and error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to create a sequence per each month (if not present, auto-create it) and use the right one on create.

By default in the `create` method it does this

```
vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('purchase.order')
```

so, you must intercept that and do your stuff, then you call the base model, something like:

```
super(model.Model, self).create([...])
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks :), I need to create a sequence per day. I planned to count the total number that day first, and then ++ as the current order's flag (the n of yyyymmdd_n). Is that a good way? Btw, I'm from Chinese, excuse my poor English please.